# A modern equivalent for the word "spinster" for women and the relevant synonym for men

Tags: word-request

In ancient English, people called a woman who had never gotten married a **sinister**, but I'm positive using it is absolete today and perhaps many youths have no sense of in many English spoken regions! So how would you normally call such an old lady/woman?

Meanwhile, I need to find a (preferably informal) word to indicate the same situation for an old boy/man.

I'm not about virginity at all! The key concept is "marriage" here.

I was wondering if there is any (preferably informal) noun/adjective to describe it.

Comment: We say Old English, not ancient English. Ancient Greek, yes. A young unmarried woman is a *bachelorette*.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no updated term for spinster -- and as not marrying is become more normal and acceptable, I wouldn't expect one to appear.

For males, the term is "confirmed bachelor" which often but not always implies the person is gay.

Again, theses terms are liable to die a natural death and not require replacements.

Comment: Thank you @reed wade; but I don't know the reason why "bachelor" should be used along with "confirmed"? Is it a fixed-term? Which semantic nenace would be appeare if I use the word "bachelor" stand-alone?

Comment: "confirmed" in a normal sense would mean that the person never intends to change status -- but in the case it's become a fixed term - https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConfirmedBachelor

Comment: But this is the quality of someone who insists to remain a bachelor, because he is absolutely against this process! @Reed wade one another question appeared to me! **What do you call a woman who is against getting mariage and never has married?**

Comment: By whatever name she prefers. I don't think there's a specific word for it.

Comment: *Bachelorhood* has very little to do with sexual preference—especially in modern times when same-sex marriages are increasingly common.